# Script to export names of vertex groups to txt file in blender 2.8

Tags: export, vertex-groups

Need a script to export all names of vertex groups in the selected model to a text file

Comment: Please include scripting or python in your flags for questions asking for scripting assistance.

Comment: Hi. Please what show what you have so far and where you're getting stuck, otherwise it sounds like you're expecting someone to write a whole script for you. Thanks.

Comment: new to scripting in blender so hard to share a syntax that I dont know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sample script for Blender 2.82a:
creates a text block in blender you can save manually.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object # select active object

if obj:
    ntxt = bpy.data.texts.new(obj.name)
    ntxt.write("Name: %s \n" % obj.name)
    ntxt.write("Location: %s \n" % obj.location)
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        ntxt.write("Vertex Groups: \n")
        for v in obj.vertex_groups:
            ntxt.write("\t Vertex Group Name: %s \n" %v.name)
```

Comment: whould I just past this as a new script and then run it with the object selected`??
sorry for being new to scripting in blender